# How to copy files in iPhone /var/mobile/Container/Data/Application/Document

Tags: iphone

I develop a test app for iPhone which needs to read some file. In simulator I copied those files showed by NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains. Now I try to run the same app in iPhone and it is showing `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ED49734D-0E61-4BB4-B3CC-D462F3BF9215/Documents/` 
location, but I don't know how to put my files in Documents folder so it can be read by my app.

Please help

Answer (score 8):

To copy your files, you need to:

1. Make sure your iPhone is jail-braked (otherwise, you wont be able to access this folder)
2. Install tweak from Cydia: Apple File Conduit "2" (this is version for iOS 8/9)
3. Transfer files with one of the following PC tools:

   - [iTools](http://itools-for-windows.en.softonic.com/)
   - [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/)

Hope this helps